# React: Get value of input[type=text] and output the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React & JavaScript in general, and could use some help with a fairly simple thing:

I want to output the input value from my text `<input>` into my `<h4>` by hitting the update button.  (Or something similar if that doesn't work)

```
return (
        <div>
            <div className="top-menu">
                <div>
                    <h1>Progress</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="progress-container">
                <h4>Progress: 43 %</h4>
                <div className="progress-bar"></div>
            </div>

            <div className="inputs">
                <label>Progress (in %)</label>
                <div className="input">
                    <form>
                        <input id="progress" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 75" />
                        <button className="button">Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The best way to do this is to control the value of the `input` in you component's state by setting props `value` and `onChange` on the `input` element.  Read up on making a "controlled input".

Comment: Actually I like Drew's answer better since you said that you only want to update after pressing the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create some progress state and use the form's `onSubmit` callback to update state and clear the input value. Render the progress state into the `h4` tag.

```
function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(43); // <-- progress state

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="top-menu">
        <div>
          <h1>Progress</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="progress-container">
        <h4>Progress: {progress} %</h4> // <-- render progress state
        <div className="progress-bar"></div>
      </div>

      <div className="inputs">
        <label>Progress (in %)</label>
        <div className="input">
          <form onSubmit={e => { // <-- form submit callback
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form action so page doesn't reload
            const { value } = e.target.progress;
            setProgress(value); // update state
            e.target.progress.value = ''; // reset input value
          }}>
            <input id="progress" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 75"></input>
            <button type="submit" className="button">Update</button> // <-- type = submit
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-get-value-of-inputtype-text-and-output-the-value]